# ASP .NET Core app and myBB forum on one server?

Tags: asp.net, apache, asp.net-core, mybb, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I want to buy VPS (Debian/Ubuntu) and host my ASP .NET Core app and myBB forum on this machine. How can I configure Apache ( and everything what is needed ) to get something like this:

- `mydomain.com` targets `ASP .NET app`
- `mydomain.com/forum` or `forum.mydomain.com` targets `myBB forum`.

I had never dig into Apache configuration so I don't know how to do this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to configure `systemd` to run your ASP.NET Core application as a service.  Then you will need to configure Apache to reverse proxy your application (requires `mod_proxy`). In addition you will want to serve the forum content locally (try `ProxyPassMatch`).

Short of doing the work for you I would suggest you read the docs and try some [tutorials](http://tattoocoder.com/using-apache-web-server-as-reverse-proxy-for-aspnetcore/) out.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most effective approach will be to use IIS. You can host myBB and you ASP.Net app without and issue.

For your Asp.net Core app follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis?tabs=aspnetcore2x) and for configuring and installing PHP (for your myBB forum) follow the tutorials [here](https://php.iis.net/).